# Can't parameterize tests by strings

Tags: c, testing, parameterized-unit-test, parameterized-tests, c-criterion

I'm trying to write a parameterized test based on some string values using the Criterion framework. As an MRE, and following [the example shown in the docs](https://criterion.readthedocs.io/en/master/parameterized.html), I wrote the following:

```
#include <criterion/criterion.h>
#include <criterion/new/assert.h>
#include <criterion/parameterized.h>
#include <stdio.h>

ParameterizedTestParameters(test_suite, test_str) {
    static char* strings[] = {"Foo", "Bar"};
    size_t strings_count = sizeof(strings)/sizeof(char*);

    return cr_make_param_array(char*, strings, strings_count);
}

ParameterizedTest(char** pstring, test_suite, test_str) {
    printf("%s\n", *pstring);
}
```

However, when I run the test, it crashes with the following output:

```
[----] tests/string_aparams.c:13: Unexpected signal caught below this line!
[FAIL] test_suite::test_str: CRASH!
[----] tests/string_aparams.c:13: Unexpected signal caught below this line!
[FAIL] test_suite::test_str: CRASH!
```

But when I tried writing a similar test based on an array of `int` parameters, it worked fine:

```
ParameterizedTestParameters(test_suite, test_int) {
    static int numbers[] = {1, 2};
    size_t numbers_count = sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(int);

    return cr_make_param_array(int, numbers, numbers_count);
}

ParameterizedTest(int* pnum, test_suite, test_int) {
    printf("%d\n", *pnum);
}
```

```
[====] Running 2 tests from test_suite:
[RUN ] test_suite::test_int
[RUN ] test_suite::test_int
1
2
[PASS] test_suite::test_int: (0.00s)
[PASS] test_suite::test_int: (0.00s)
```

What could be the problem with first snippet of code?

## UPDATE:

After re-reading the docs a couple of times, the following passage from the [same page](https://criterion.readthedocs.io/en/master/parameterized.html) made me think:

> Any dynamic memory allocation done from a ParameterizedTestParameter
> function must be done with cr_malloc, cr_calloc, or cr_realloc

Perhabs using `"Foo"` and `"Bar"` inside `{"Foo", "Bar"}` is dynamically allocating space for the two strings and I should instead use `cr_malloc` to allocate space for them. I'm not sure if that is the case, but this made me try another approach:

```
#include <criterion/criterion.h>
#include <criterion/new/assert.h>
#include <criterion/parameterized.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRINGS_COUNT 2 
#define STRINGS (char*[]){"Foo", "Bar"}

ParameterizedTestParameters(test_suite, test_str) {
    static char* strings[STRINGS_COUNT];
    
    for(size_t k = 0; k < STRINGS_COUNT; k++) {
        strings[k] = cr_malloc(strlen(STRINGS[k]) + 1);
        strcpy(strings[k], STRINGS[k]);
    }

    return cr_make_param_array(char*, strings, STRINGS_COUNT);
}

ParameterizedTest(char* *pstring, test_suite, test_str) {
    printf("%s\n", *pstring);
}
```

When running the above test, the following output is displayed:

```
[RUN ] test_suite::test_str
Foo
[PASS] test_suite::test_str: (0.00s)
[RUN ] test_suite::test_str
Bar
```

Is my assumption that using the initializer `{"Foo", "Bar"}` dynamically allocate space for the two strings correct? And, if not, why would the first test crash while the third succeed?

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, I tried printing the result and it gave me 2 unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused :-) I'd prefer `sizeof strings / sizeof *strings;` Btw, make it `static const char* strings[] = {"Foo", "Bar"};` since you are not allowed to change the string literals anyway.